# regular expression to get only letters between a look behind and look ahead

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract only the letters from "130b2c94-22ba-4584-b18a-899eb4be045d"

```
<input type="hidden" name="logonInfo.forceAuthn" value="false" id="sSignOnauthenticateUser_logonInfo_forceAuthn"/>
<input type="hidden" name="logonInfo.inResponseTO" value="_130b2c94-22ba-4584-b18a-899eb4be045d" id="sSignOnauthenticateUser_logonInfo_inResponseTO"/>
<input type="hidden" name="logonInfo.issuerUrl"
```

I have tried

```
(?<=name="logonInfo.inResponseTO" value="_).*(?=" id="sSignOnauthenticateUser)
```

to extracts the string I need, but I need to break it down further to only the letters

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse HTML, use a DOM parser library.

Comment: A regexp can only match a contiguous substring. You should extract the whole string with a regexp, then remove the numbers from it with other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DOM Parser. This will reliably interpret the HTML and give you a DOM.

Then use a CSS selector query to find the `input` elements that have a `value` attribute which has a value that starts with underscore.

Finally remove all non-letters in that found value using a regex:

```js
const html = `
<input type="hidden" name="logonInfo.forceAuthn" value="false" id="sSignOnauthenticateUser_logonInfo_forceAuthn"/>
<input type="hidden" name="logonInfo.inResponseTO" value="_130b2c94-22ba-4584-b18a-899eb4be045d" id="sSignOnauthenticateUser_logonInfo_inResponseTO"/>
<input type="hidden" name="logonInfo.issuerUrl" >`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
for (const input of doc.querySelectorAll("input[value^=_]")) {
  const letters = input.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "");
  console.log(input.name, ":", letters);
}
```